# Methods to Make Site Content Editable

Tags: php, html, database, contenteditable

I've been doing some preliminary research into making the content on the internal, customer support website I maintain editable by the managers in the department, to make it easier to update the site's content when I'm not available to do so.

The design concept is that the manager would access a login-secured Edit mode on the site, and click a button next to the section of content they wish to change. Once they've completed their changes, upon exiting out of Edit mode, their changes would be written back to the site, where they would be permanently recorded for the customer support agents who use the site to see the updated content.

The easiest way to do this, if I understand right, would require have a SQL database that stores the actual content-- when the page loads, it grabs the HTML from the field on the table that matches with the appropriate DIV and plugs it into place. Any changes to the content would be written back to that field, through a PHP script, where the new information would be permanently stored.

My trouble is, that I don't have the ability at the moment to run a server-side database to store all of the site content. So I am trying to come up with a solution to store all of my data without having to rely on a database server to do so. Are there ways that I can go about storing tables of information that a site can read/write to, without using a SQL server of some sort?

Comment: No, you need a server to persist data. Whether that server stores the data in a database or a file on disk is irrelevant. If you have enough control over your server to come up with some non-database storage solution, you can necessarily implement a proper solution *with* a database. You don't need a second machine for this, and you don't have to *buy* any software. Just use SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

This is a whole database contained in a single file that resides anywhere in your file system.  It doesn't require running a SQL server and still gives you all the benfits of using one! Support is built-in to PHP and using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you connect very easily:

```
$db = '/path/to.file/my_database.sqlite';

try {
    $conn = new PDO('sqlite:' . $db);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('Fatal error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

This will even create the database file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: That sounds like it would do exactly what I would need. So there's no need for me to download any of the binaries from the SQLite site to get started with this? Because that would allow me to dive right into restructuring the site to communicate with that database.

Comment: If you have PHP (and a web server running it) then you have everything you need.  It might be that you need to enable PDO and PDO_SQLite in your php.ini file, but otherwise you should be able to get cracking right away. The link to the SQLite site is just for reference.